# Trying to build Tomcat 6 from source: Ant doesn't download libs

Tags: macos, tomcat, ant

I am trying to build Tomcat 6 or 7 on my machine from provided source codes.

I have checked out the sources from repository and ran the ant build.

In the very beginning of the build Ant needs to download the libs Tomcat needs. In the 6th version it is done by separate command 'ant download', in the 7th version this command is incorporated into build.xml.

The problem is that Ant cannot download the libs Tomcat needs for build while trying to build both the versions.

It stops here:

> trydownload:
>         [get] Getting: http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.1.24/source/tomcat-native-1.1.24-src.tar.gz
>         [get] To: /Users/dmitrijskorov/libraries/tomcat-native-1.1.24/tomcat-native.tar.gz

After printing this nothing happens. No errors, no end of execution. The file itself is created inside the folder for downloads, but its size is 111KB instead of 262KB if I download it manually. Ping of that server also evaluates ok.

Looks like I have problems with Ant download task.

Probably the reason is some proxy settings I need to provide to Ant. But I dont know how to find out my proxy settings. All settings in all browsers and OS point to automatic detection of proxies and thus I cannot setup proxy in Ant build. And I dont know whether I need this at all.

MacOs Lion, Tomcat 6 or 7, Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ant 1.7 or later you can use the `-autoproxy` option to Ant to tell it to use the proxy settings from the operating system

```
ant -autoproxy download
```

Ref: [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html)

Comment: Thanks Ian, good idea, but it still stops... probably proxy is not an issue.

Comment: So finally I downloaded the files manually, I close the question, Ian's answer is useful.

Comment: as for ant 1.8.4, tomcat trunk as of date and windows 7, the -autoproxy option doesn't work yet you can still set the proxy properties in the build.properties as stated in the docs.